# In REACT When I try to update date using setState but it doesn't change date it always show current date but in console it shows the changed date

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

```
  **import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import moment from 'moment'
    import {Form, Formik, Field, ErrorMessage} from 'formik'
    import TodoDataService from '../../api/todo/TodoDataService'
    import AuthenticationService from './AuthenticationService'
    
    class TodoComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                id:this.props.params.id,
                description:'',
                targetDate: moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            }
            this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
            this.validate = this.validate.bind(this);
        }
        componentDidMount(){
            let username = AuthenticationService.getLoginUserName()
            TodoDataService.retrieveTodo(username, this.state.id)
            .then(response => this.setState({
                description: response.data.description,
                targetDate: moment(response.data.targetDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            }))
        }
        validate(values){
            let error = {}
            if(!values.description){
                error.description = "Enter a Description"
            }
            else if(values.description.length<5){
                error.description = "Enter atleast 5 Characters in Description"
            }
            if(!moment(values.targetDate).isValid()){
                error.targetDate="Enter a valid date"
            }
            return error
        }
        onSubmit(values){
            let username = AuthenticationService.getLoginUserName()
    
            let todo={
                id: this.state.id,
                description:values.description,
                targetDate:values.targetDate
            }
            console.log(values)
            if(this.state.id === -1){
                TodoDataService.createTodo(username, todo)
                .then(()=> this.props.navigate('/todos'))
            }else{
            TodoDataService.updateTodo(username, this.state.id,
               todo).then(() => this.props.navigate('/todos'))
        }
    
        }
        render() {
            let {description, targetDate} = this.state;
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Update Todo Form  </h1>
                      <div className="container">
                        <Formik initialValues = {{description, targetDate}} onSubmit={this.onSubmit} 
                        validateOnChange={false} validateOnBlur={false} validate={this.validate} enableReinitialize={true}>
                        {
                            (props) =>(
                                 <Form>
                                    <ErrorMessage name="description" component="div" className="alert alert-warning"/>
                                    <ErrorMessage name="targetDate" component="div" className="alert alert-warning"/>
                                    <fieldset className="form-group">
                                        <label>Description</label>
                                        <Field className="form-control" type="text" name="description"/>
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <fieldset className="form-group">
                                        <label>Target Date</label>
                                        <Field className="form-control" type="date" name="targetDate"/>
                                    </fieldset>
                                     <button className="btn btn-success" type="submit" >Save</button>
    
                                 </Form>
                            )
                        }
                        
                        </Formik>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    export default TodoComponent;**





    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import TodoDataService from '../../api/todo/TodoDataService';
    import AuthenticationService from './AuthenticationService';
    import moment from 'moment';
    
    class ListTodoComponent extends Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state={
                todos:[],
                message:null
            }
            this.deleteTodoClicked = this.deleteTodoClicked.bind(this);
            this.refreshTodos = this.refreshTodos.bind(this);
            this.updateTodoClicked = this.updateTodoClicked.bind(this);
            this.addTobeClicked = this.addTobeClicked.bind(this);
        }
        componentDidMount(){
            this.refreshTodos();
    
        }
        addTobeClicked(){
            this.props.navigate(`/todos/-1`)
        }
        deleteTodoClicked(id){
            let username = AuthenticationService.getLoginUserName()
            TodoDataService.deleteTodo(username, id)
             .then( response =>{
                 this.setState({message:`Delete of todo id ${id} Successfull`})
                 this.refreshTodos()
             })
           
                
        }
        refreshTodos(){
            let username = AuthenticationService.getLoginUserName()
            TodoDataService.retrieveAllTodos(username)
            .then(
                response => {
                    this.setState({todos:response.data})
                }
            )
        }
        updateTodoClicked(id){
            console.log("updated");
            this.props.navigate(`/todos/${id}`)
            
    
        }
        render(){
            return (
                <div>
                    <div className="container">
                    <h1>List of Todos</h1>
                    {this.state.message &&<div className="alert alert-success">{this.state.message}</div>}
                    <table className="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Is Completed?</th>
                                <th>Target Date</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                                <th>Update</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {
                            this.state.todos.map( 
                                todo =>
                            <tr key={todo.id}>
                                <td>{todo.id}</td>
                                <td>{todo.description}</td>
                                <td>{String(todo.done)}</td>
                                <td>{moment(todo.targetDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}</td>
                                <td><button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={() => this.deleteTodoClicked(todo.id)}>Delete</button></td>
                                <td><button className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => this.updateTodoClicked(todo.id)}>Update</button></td>
                            </tr>
                            )
                        }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div className="row">
                        <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.addTobeClicked}>Add Todo</button>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    export default ListTodoComponent
```

When I try to add date but date remain same date but in console it shows the new added date why new added date don't show in screen.
When I try to add date but date remain same date but in console it shows the new added date why new added date don't show in screen.
When I try to add date but date remain same date but in console it shows the new added date why new added date don't show in screen.